# SQL exercise on SQL-ex, exercise 37

Tags: sql

Exercise 37. Find classes for which only one ship exists in the database (including the Outcomes table).

This was my query:

```
select ship 
from outcomes 
where ship not in (select class
                   from ships
                   group by class
                   having count(name)>1)
  and ship in (select class 
               from classes)
```

This returned the correct dataset on the first (available) database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking database.

Can anyone explain why this is wrong? I have seen examples of correct answers, but I'm interested in know what is wrong with this one as it returns the right answer.

EDIT: Database Info:
The database of naval ships that took part in World War II is under consideration. The database consists of the following relations:
Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)
Ships(name, class, launched)
Battles(name, date)
Outcomes(ship, battle, result)
Ships in classes all have the same general design. A class is normally assigned either the name of the first ship built according to the corresponding design, or a name that is different from any ship name in the database. The ship whose name is assigned to a class is called a lead ship.
The Classes relation includes the name of the class, type (can be either bb for a battle ship, or bc for a battle cruiser), country the ship was built in, the number of main guns, gun caliber (bore diameter in inches), and displacement (weight in tons). The Ships relation holds information about the ship name, the name of its corresponding class, and the year the ship was launched. The Battles relation contains names and dates of battles the ships participated in, and the Outcomes relation - the battle result for a given ship (may be sunk, damaged, or OK, the last value meaning the ship survived the battle unharmed).
Notes: 1) The Outcomes relation may contain ships not present in the Ships relation. 2) A ship sunk can’t participate in later battles. 3) For historical reasons, lead ships are referred to as head ships in many exercises.4) A ship found in the Outcomes table but not in the Ships table is still considered in the database. This is true even if it is sunk.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the table definitions and sample data, and expected output

Comment: Your task is not clear. You may want to add some sample data and the sesired result to your question (use [Edit]).

Comment: Hm. How come query you posted answers the question (as you said "this returned the correct dataset") if it SELECTs SHIP, while question instructs you to FIND CLASSES?

Comment: Hi @OldProgrammer and PM 77-1, I've linked the question which provides info about the databased etc, sorry for not including that sooner.

Comment: @Littlefoot Thanks for getting back to me. I've added more info on the database via the link edited in my qu. Basically the table outcomes has the column 'ships' which also represents the class. The link describes the database setup better than I can https://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref Thank you.

Comment: People here don't click on random links.  All relevant information should be in the question text.

Comment: @OldProgrammer No worries - I've edited. Let me know if you need more info

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  class
FROM
(
    SELECT  class
    FROM ships
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  distinct class
    FROM classes, outcomes
    WHERE classes.class = outcomes.ship
    AND ship not IN ( SELECT name FROM ships)
) t
GROUP BY  class
HAVING COUNT(class) = 1;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.